# JavaScript Countdown Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, testing

I'm writing some JavaScript to take an array of 9 numbers from 1 - 9 which are out of order, and return a countdown from 10 - 1 as a string.

For example:

**Input:** [4, 9, 3, 10, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1, 5];

**Output:** "10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 liftoff!"

**JavaScript Test:**

```
Test.assertEquals(liftoff([2, 8, 10, 9, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5]),"10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 liftoff!")
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function liftoff(instructions){

  var countdown = "";
  var start = 10;

  for (start; start >= 1; start--) {

    for (var i = 0; i < instructions.length; i++) {

      if (instructions[i] == start) {
        var count = instructions[i].toString();
        countdown += count + " ";
      }

    }

  }

  countdown += " liftoff!";
  console.log(countdown);
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
Expected: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 liftoff!, instead got: undefined
```

Why is it **undefined**?

Comment: What does `instructions = liftoff [4, 9, 3, 10, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1, 5]` mean?

Comment: What is the question? Did you ever call this function? Any errors?

Comment: he seems to wants to sort an array numerically and keep liftoff at the end of it

Answer (score 4):

```
function liftoff(instructions) {
  return instructions
  // sort into correct order
  .sort(function(a, b){
    return b - a;
  })
  // convert into string with spaces
  .join(' ') +
  // add 'lift off!
  ' lift off!';
}
```

Comment: Doesn't QUITE do what the OP said, as post mentioned input being 1-9 and the countdown running from 10 down to 1. But...that also doesn't make a lot of sense, so I'd have given much the same answer you did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more option to give you what you want:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html />
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Countdown" id="btnCountdown"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var countdown = document.getElementById("btnCountdown");
var instructions = [5, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1, 9, 7, 8];
countdown.onclick = function () {
    var sortedInstructions = instructions.sort();

    for (var i = instructions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var text = document.createTextNode(sortedInstructions[i]);
        var el = document.createElement("P");
        el.appendChild(text);
        document.body.appendChild(el);

        if (i == 0) {
            var liftOff = document.createTextNode("Lift Off!");
            var lastEl = document.createElement("P");
            lastEl.appendChild(liftOff);
            document.body.appendChild(lastEl);
        }
    }
}
```